# Joining Access tables to ArcGIS layers

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-joins, ms-access

I'm attempting to Join an Access query/table from an .accdb to a layer in ArcGIS Pro 3.0.

I've made an OLE DB connection to the Access database, and made a query to get the table in access able to be added to the map. This has all been successful, and I can open and access the table in ArcGIS Pro with all data available. However, when I attempt to join the table, the join produces 0 connections.

I am not using the active database right now, but rather a test one, so I know that there are matches because I added the identification sequences, which are a combination of letters and numbers that identify the location of the object, directly from the table I want to join it to. I've checked the variables and changed around the variable type in both Access and in Pro to test I think every possible combination. I've also tested both using online versions of the data in ArcGIS Online, and offline versions in a geodatabase without success on joining. Is there an additional step to make this join possible?

The catch to this is that ideally I would like to maintain the ability to edit the data in the Access database, as this data is still active and being changed, as otherwise I would simply export it and join it as an Excel table.

Comment: Going to speculate here, ArcPro is known to not work well with Access, although now being able to add an OLE link is a big improvement. But I guess the join is failing because the tables don't have ObjectID fields?